# Describing spacetime with qubits

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, black-holes, ads-cft, black-hole-firewall

Susskind in one of his lectures at PiTP 2018 on Complexity and Gravity talks about describing black holes as a qubit system, comprising qubits of the order of the entropy of the black hole. This is basically a $\textit{minimal description}$ in the sense that one could basically model the entire, say, AdS space, in which the BH exists, as a qubit system, and then the BH would just be one of the features in such a description. Now obviously that would require a tremendously large (if not infinite) number of qubits but I have heard people talk about describing space-time, in general, with qubits. My questions are the following:

1. Is it possible to model AdS space-time (or any other spacetime) as a qubit system? (relevant references would be greatly appreciated)
2. How many qubits would be required to model the entire AdS spacetime? Have there been any attempts to calculate the volume of an AdS space? Or equivalently, any attempts to "count" the number of states in an N=4 Supersymmetric Yang-Mills theory? (again, please post relevant references)

Link to the lecture notes: https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.11563
(Link to the video lectures can be found in the notes.)

Comment: Could you also please post the relevant reference to the lecture you mentioned?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.11563. He talks about this in the second lecture in these notes.

Comment: Thank you for the reference